# How many different ways of choosing a committee of 7 individuals from 10 officers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many different ways of choosing a committee of 7 individuals from 10 officers with at most four over the age of 65 (Your final answer should be written using the ∑ Symbol) There are 6 individuals over the age of 65.

Could someone provide an answer with an explanation ?

Comment: Look up Vandermonde's Identity and make some modifications to it to fit your answer. This should be a good enough hint ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you think a bit, there are just $2$ cases to consider:

$3$ young - $4$ old, or $4$ young - $3$ old, thus

$$\binom43\binom64 + \binom44\binom63,\;\; or\sum_{k=3}^4 \binom4{k}\binom6{7-k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd attack it.

I'd add up the number of ways of getting exactly $0$, exactly $1$, ... , exactly $4$ 65-and-older members on the committee.

Let's say we have $4$.  First choose the $4$ 65+ members, then choose the $3$ younger members.  This gives $_6C_4 \cdot _4C_3$ possibilities.

Write down the other four, then see how the subscripts change to fashion your $\sum$.